# Using Spring Messages on custom Error page eg. 404

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, internationalization

I have a Spring 3.1 based webapplication. On case of an 404 error i have configured an 404 page within web.xml.

```
<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/404.jsp</location>
</error-page>
```

The 404 does a request forward to a Controller

```
<jsp:forward page="/mvc/error/404" />
```

The Controller will return a custom view displaying a customized 404 Design. This all works well except on thing. Messages wich are defined as jsp tag

```
<spring:message code="..." />
```

aren't displayed. I always get the code but not the message.

Any Ideas on this ?

regards
Tim

Comment: Have you tried adding attributes to the Model and have the ModelAndView to redirect?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Initialy i don't want to redirect, as i try to keep the original status of the 404. To answer your question: yes if can add attributes to the Model and display them on the page, but if have a lot of messages eg. navigationitems wich i cant add to the model. One other thing is that it looks like the container tries to resolve the messages as i see errors within the log that no message is found for given key. it all works if i call the url direct.

Comment: finaly i got it. Was no Spring Problem - everything works as expected. But some other service (3rd party) threw an exception. thx

Answer (score 0):

As  mentioned before, finally it wasn't a spring problem. All my thoughs were correct. Just another lib caused that my message was overwritten by an empty string - so the key was returned. Thx for thinking about my question.